# jQuery UI Datepicker - Hide set days per week as well as specific dates

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, datepicker

I am currently using an array with a set of specific dates in conjunction with the beforeShowDay option in jQuery UI Datepicker to block specific days from selection. I woudl like to also block all Tuesdays from being selected. The only way I can think of would be to push those dates to my array, but that seems rather long-winded. Can anyone suggest another way to achive this?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

`beforeShowDay` passes a `Date` object to its function, so you can just use `.getDay()` to check what day of the week it is:

```
$( "#datepicker" ).datepicker({
  beforeShowDay: function(d) {
    if ( d.getDay() === 2 ) {
      return [false, "", ""];
    }
    // else do the custom date check
  }
});
```

ref: [`Date.getDay()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/getDay)